# talend "com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error getting access token for service account: Read timed out"

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

I have a Talend code where its simply querying data from Big Query, attached is the screenshot my code. And when I place my credential file(json private key file with client id and URI) in my local drive and ran the job using LocalHost , am not facing any issue code ran fine. But when I try to run in remote server (linux) its throwing below error. The same code was working fine in same remote server a month ago, now for past one week facing this issue and we could not figure out why.
The same job is running fine in some other remote server and in localhost.

Exception in component tBigQueryInput_1 (job_test)
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error getting access token for service account: Read timed out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf0RS.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilh2U.png)

How to fix this, we are not sure why this time out is happening only in few servers and not all.